# My Roblox Studio script is sometimes having errors.. idk why

Tags: macos, lua, roblox

So.. I've been coding to make a GUI show the quantity of currency of a player, the datastore API works perfectly but the local script doesn't (it's local because else it would just update it each time a player's currency gets updated and would be a mess being the opposite of what I want to)
and well... sometimes it loads the currency into the GUI but other times it just stays on the original text: "Label" instead of my current currency (4600)
here's the proof

What normally happens and should always happen

[image: No script output with currency loaded in GUI]

What sometimes happens and shouldn't happen:

[image: Script output with original text "label" instead of current currency "4600"]
here's the script, I've tried putting waits on the start but the original code is inside the while true do..

```
wait(game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("Data")
wait(game.Players.LocalPlayer.Data:WaitForChild("Bells"))
while true do
    script.Parent.TextLabel.Text = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("Data"):WaitForChild("Bells").Value
    wait() --wait is for not making the loop break and stop the whole script
end
```

well.. if you want to see if data is really in the player, here's the script, it requires a API (DataStore2)

```
--[Animal Crossing Roblox Edition Data Store]--
            --Bryan99354--
        --Module not mine--
--Made with a AlvinBlox tutorial--
--·.·.*[Get Data Store, do not erase]*.·.·--

local DataStore2 = require(1936396537)

--[Default Values]--

local DefaultValue_Bells = 300
local DefaultValue_CustomClothes = 0

--[Data Store Functions]--

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    --[Data stores]--
    local BellsDataStore = DataStore2("Bells",player)

    local Data = Instance.new("Folder",player)
    Data.Name = "Data"

    Bells = Instance.new("IntValue",Data)
    Bells.Name = "Bells"

    local CustomClothesDataStore = DataStore2("CustomClothes",player)

    local CustomClothes = Instance.new("IntValue",Data)
    CustomClothes.Name = "CustomClothes"

    local function CustomClothesUpdate(UpdatedValue)
        CustomClothes.Value = CustomClothesDataStore:Get(UpdatedValue)
    end

    local function BellsUpdate(UpdatedValue)
        Bells.Value = BellsDataStore:Get(UpdatedValue)
    end

    BellsUpdate(DefaultValue_Bells)
    CustomClothesUpdate(DefaultValue_CustomClothes)

    BellsDataStore:OnUpdate(BellsUpdate)
    CustomClothesDataStore:OnUpdate(CustomClothesUpdate)
end)

--[test and reference functions]--

workspace.TestDevPointGiver.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    local BellsDataStore = DataStore2("Bells",player)
    BellsDataStore:Increment(50,DefaultValue_Bells)
end)
workspace.TestDevCustomClothesGiver.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    local CustomClothesDataStore = DataStore2("CustomClothes",player)
    CustomClothesDataStore:Increment(50,DefaultValue_CustomClothes)
end)
```

the code that creates "Data" and "Bells" is located in the comment: Data Stores
the only script that gets the issue is the short one with no reason :<
I hope that you can help me :3
@Night94 I tryed your script but it also failed sometimes
[image: New script with same random script output error]

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in your LocalScript is a little off with the waits. With that fixed, it works every time. Also, I would use an event handler instead of updating the value with a loop:

```
game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("Data"):WaitForChild("Bells").Changed:Connect(function(value)
    script.Parent.TextLabel.Text = value
end)
```

Comment: output (sometimes):
    Stack Begin
    Script'Players.bryan99354.PlayerGUI.BellsGUI.LocalScript', Line 1
    Stack End

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. If you scroll up in your output pane, what does it say in the line above "Stack Begin" ?

Comment: it says:
11:33:04.906 - SliceCenter ((499.000000,112.000000), (501.000000,113.000000)) is outside the bounds of imageOffset ((492.000000,112.000000), (493.000000,113.000000)) for GuiImage[CoreGui.TopBar.TopBarFrame.RightFrame.MoreMenu.MoreMenuContainer.OverlayContextualMenu.PositionFrame.BaseMenu.ClippingFrame.ScrollingFrame.cell 2]

Comment: 11:33:04.907 - SliceCenter ((507.000000,112.000000), (509.000000,113.000000)) is outside the bounds of imageOffset ((500.000000,112.000000), (501.000000,113.000000)) for GuiImage[CoreGui.TopBar.TopBarFrame.RightFrame.MoreMenu.MoreMenuContainer.OverlayContextualMenu.PositionFrame.BaseMenu.ClippingFrame.ScrollingFrame.cell 2.StateOverlay]
11:33:09.846 - Infinite yield possible on 'Players.bryan99354:WaitForChild("Data")'

Comment: but that's Roblox's GUI

Comment: sometimes... the Instance.new("Folder",player) doesn't happens idk why

Comment: most of the time it does but others it doesn't

Comment: must be a platform problem, thanks for your help tho, I'm still using your script ^^